# Changing transform of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, transform

I'm trying have a function in my app that changes the transform of my `UIImageView`(their positions and scale) when I tap the view. Each image should move to the same position of the other images to give it a scrolling effect. For example, if I have images 'a', 'b' and 'c', image 'a' should transform to the position and scale of 'b', image 'b' should transform to the position and scale of 'c' and finally image 'c' should transform to the position and scale of 'a'.

I've managed to get it working as intended for the FIRST tap. But every tap after goes out of position and scale.

Here is the code:

```
@objc private func tapHandler(){

    for index in 0...2{
        var transform = CGAffineTransform()

        if (circlesIV[index].tag==0){
            transform = transforms[0].translatedBy(x: +100.0, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        }
        else if (circlesIV[index].tag==1){
            transform = transforms[1].translatedBy(x: -200.0, y: 0.0)
        }
        else {
            transform = transforms[2].translatedBy(x: +100.0, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
        }
        circlesIV[index].transform = transform
    }

    var tempTag = circlesIV[0].tag
    circlesIV[0].tag = circlesIV[1].tag
    circlesIV[1].tag = circlesIV[2].tag
    circlesIV[2].tag = tempTag 
}
```

transforms is an array with the original transforms of the `UIImageView` and circlesIV is an array of the `UIImageView` (there are 3 images).

EDIT: I think the problem is related to the auto constraints used to set the images.

```
circlesIV[0].centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topHalf.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
circlesIV[1].centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topHalf.centerXAnchor, constant: +100).isActive = true
circlesIV[2].centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topHalf.centerXAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true

for index in 0...2{
    circlesIV[index].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    circlesIV[index].centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topHalf.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    if(index==0){
        circlesIV[index].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        circlesIV[index].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    } else {
        circlesIV[index].widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
        circlesIV[index].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the `transforms` array? Are the “original transforms” of the image views something different than identity?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem, but not sure how to fix it. I set the images transform using auto constraints. Ill add that part of the code to the section.

Comment: don't you think using pure autolayout is better instead of transforms? Now you're using both

Comment: The idea is that I'm trying to animate the images to change position on a tap gesture. I was just using autolayout to place the images down then I wanted to be able to change their position and scale on a tap.

Comment: So what happens on 2nd and 3rd tap? By looking at your code 2nd tap will be (tag = 0 for example) translated by 200, 3rd tap it will be translated by 300...

Comment: So thats when it gets strange. After the first tap I change the tags to match the circles new positions. Because circleIV[2] is now where circle[0] was, I have the tags change. That way when i run the loop again on the next tap they will be transformed following the rules in the first if statement. Which is what it SHOULD do, move it by 100 and scale it by 0.5 but it doesn't.

Comment: The strange thing is, when I try just moving the UIImageViews position and NOT scale, everything works perfectly. When i try to scale the UIImageView without moving them, it again works fine. Its only when i try to do both does it go wildly out of position